# How to set variable once for different pages in one window

Tags: javascript

I want set boolean flag for current window. I will use this flag on all pages in this window. `LocalStorage` bad idea, becouse it set flag permanently for all windows. How can I do it?

Comment: sessionStorage is less permanent(than localStorage) and can be used to do roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Like jQuery, jQuery attached to window and work as a global variable that can access from any window
you can do something like...

```
window.my_flag = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the window’s name `window.name` to store the information. This method is often used to modify the name of a window, after the window has been created. It only works as long as the same window/tab is used.

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP or JSP session and then retrieve your value in any page using AJAX.

You should have an ajax request to initialize your value first. Then you should set/update/read your boolean value accordingly using AJAX.

Let me know if you need details.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies:

set the cookie :

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Get the cookie:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)